# Spring - @Configuration - AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - problem on server

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, war, spring-annotations

I tried several solutions. I´ve read a lot on Internet. I did not find a correct answer.
I will explain :

This is my configuration file :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:src/property/config.properties")
public class ConfigProperties {

    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;

    @Value("${email}")
    private String email;
    
    @Value("${phone}")
    private String phone;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This is the test class :

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ctx.register(ConfigProperties.class);
ctx.refresh();
ConfigProperties myService = ctx.getBean(ConfigProperties.class);
```

Everything works on local when I launch the app.
I got errors when I tried this configuration on the server :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext (Module "deployment.HotelCancun.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext (Module "deployment.HotelCancun.war" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

Coud you please help me ?

Regards,

** I use server Wildfly 21

Comment: How did you try this configuration exactly on your server? Spring has support for developing servlet based and reactive applications.

Comment: Yes I did. This is exactly the same configuration.

Comment: I´ve worked on this issue since last week...

Comment: Do I need to add a new configuration file or something that I forgot ?

Comment: I reset the project. Every works again !!!